# Update Hyperlink in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, flow, ms-flow

I am trying to update hyperlink on SharePoint list with MS Flow, but I am getting error:

> The property '_metadata' does not exist on type 'SP.FieldUrlValue'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.

I am using Send an HTTP to SharePoint List name is "Archive" and it has hyperlink column "Link".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `__metadata` (with two underscores) and `_metadata`.

**References**:

1. [Updating sharepoint hyperlink field via flow not updating](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Updating-sharepoint-hyperlink-field-via-flow-not-updating/td-p/202976).
2. [Setting and Updating SharePoint Hyperlink fields in Flow](https://collab365.community/setting-updating-sharepoint-hyperlink-fields-flow-logic-apps/).

Comment: Thanks I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Like Mr Ganesh said, you are missing an underscore and everything look well.

[image]

well, I did not do this to repeat what Mr Ganesh already said and answered, I just would to recommend to use **SharePoint Insider extension** in your Browser, install it and explore it features, it will impress you and help you to figure out the endpoints you need and the content of each field ("__metadata","Id" ...etc), Since i started using it, my mistake has decreased and I have discovered a lot of things with it.

[SharePoint Insider extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-insider/gjckpigahcbffmeofjfedlffddhfidhj?hl=en)

Good luck.